# Parsing innertext of html

Tags: c#, html, parsing, html-agility-pack, innertext

This is part of html that i am parsing

```
<li><a href="http://some.link.com/4DFR6DJ43Y/sessionid?ticket=ASDSIDFK32423421" target="_blank">http://some.link.com/4DFR6DJ43Y/sessionid?ticket=ASDSIDFK32423421</a></li>
```

I want to get `http://some.link.com/4DFR6DJ43Y/sessionid?ticket=ASDSIDFK32423421` as an output.

So far i have tried

```
        HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();
        document.LoadHtml(responseFromServer);


        var link = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//a");

        if (link != null)
        {  
            if(link.innerText.Contains("ticket"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(link.InnerText);
            }
        }
```

... but output is null (no inner texts are found).

Comment: use link.innerText.Contains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably because *the first link* in your HTML document as returned by `SelectSingleNode()`, doesn't contains text `"ticket"`. You can check for the target text in XPath directly , like so :

```
var link = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//a[contains(.,'ticket')]");

if (link != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(link.InnerText);
}
```

or using LINQ style if you like :

```
var link = document.DocumentNode
                   .SelectNodes("//a")
                   .OfType<HtmlNode>()
                   .FirstOrDefault(o => o.InnerText.Contains("ticket"));

if (link != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(link.InnerText);
}
```

Comment: Xpath solution is exactly what i need. Short and sweet. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You provided a piece of code that won't compile because `innerText` is not defined. If you try this code, you'll probably get what you asked for:

```
HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();
document.LoadHtml(html);

var link = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//a");

if (link != null)
{
    if(link.InnerText.Contains("ticket"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(link.InnerText);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you its a typo when copy/pasting. This returns NULL tho. I have settled on Xpath solution posted above. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML Agility Pack instead of HTML Document then you can do deep parsing in HTML. for more information please see the following information.
See the following link.
[How to use HTML Agility pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack)

Comment: HtmlDocument is from Html Agility Pack